# Why does "sudo ifconfig eth0 down" followed by "sudo ifconfig eth0 up" stop dhcp?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ifconfig

I am playing around in Ubuntu 12.04 trying to learn about networking. I learned that you can delete a network interface by running

```
sudo ifconfig name_of_network_interface down
```

However, when I do the inverse operation

```
sudo ifconfig name_of_network_interface up
```

I cannot connect to my DNS server, and obviously I can't use firefox. I managed to figure out that if I ran

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

this will cause everything to run as expected. This brings me to the question asked in the title of this post; why is it that deleting a network interface also stops dhcp from working?

The best answer to this post would be one that describes the important operations that occur when a network interface is brought down and then brought back up.

Comment: I switched between static and dhcp today and just doing this caused mine to be unable to reach the DNS servers. I had to sudo ifconfig eth0 down and then up to get it to reach again. This isn't an answer but I'd be curious as to why it seems to die easy. I'm a windows native so there's just some Linux things that seem... different.