Kali does not detect Eth1 - VMware Pro
Working on an assignment where I need to create a new network adaptor (Host only) in VMware an I need to enter the following
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.150.129 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo route add default gw 192.168.150.242 eth1

However I get an error as the output
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
eth1: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
255.255.255.: Host name lookup failure

What am I doing wrong?

Does https://superuser.com/questions/804840/why-does-sudo-ifconfig-eth0-down-followed-by-sudo-ifconfig-eth0-up-stop-dhcp help?

The issue they are describing is in regard to not being able to simultaneously use eth0 and eth1. In my case, Kali doesn't register eth1 at all. I have restarted my VM and my network adapter is configured correctly. Clueless as to what the issue is.
